# Rate used for approval on a 5/5 ARM?

Tags: mortgage, interest-rate, mortgage-qualification, adjustable-rate-mortgage, debt-to-income-ratio

When applying for a 5/5 ARM with a 2% cap each adjustment, a 6% lifetime cap, that starts out at 2.5%, what rate will the lenders generally use to qualify you for the loan when computing your debt to income ratio (DTI)?  Is it the 2.5% initial rate, the maximum rate at the first adjustment of 4.5%, or the lifetime max 6% adjustment or 8.5%?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rate used to qualify you is the initial rate. This can be a source of problems if the new rate jumps to a level that the borrowers can't afford.

One problem during the last housing bubble was loans that were approved where the only reason they could afford the loan was because they initial payments were artificially low. When the loan reset to a normal rate or when prices failed to continue to rise those borrowers ran into problems.

It is good to look at how high the rate can go, and have a plan for handling those higher rates. Options include refinancing to a fixed rate or selling the house.

Comment: I saw on one place that for a 5/1 they use initial plus 2%, but on a 7/1, just the initial.  So you are saying a 5/5 is treated the way a 7/1 generally is?